# window.open(url, '_blank') doesn't work in Dynamics 365 for phone

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-mobile

I am trying to use this below script to open url of an entity view:

```
    static openClientForm(pageType?: string, entityName?: string, id?: string) {
            const url = `ms-dynamicsxrm://?pagetype=${pageType}&etn=${entityName}&id=${id}`;
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            return;
}
```

but the problem is `window.open()` doesn't work in Dynamics 365 for phone app in my android device. It does nothing when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below supported method:

```
Xrm.Navigation.openForm(entityFormOptions,formParameters).then(successCallback,errorCallback);
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform)